# Is dollar operator ($) considered bad form? Why?

Tags: haskell, coding-style

In Haskell, I often write expressions with $'s. I find it quite natural and readable, but I sometimes read it is bad form and do not understand why it should be.

Comment: Do you have a reference for where it is described as bad form?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following are all good form:

```
foo = bar . baz . quux
foo x = bar . baz . quux $ x
foo x = (bar . baz . quux) x
foo x = bar (baz (quux x))
```

I've put them in rough order of my preference, though as always taste varies, and context may demand a different choice. I've also occasionally seen

```
foo = bar
    . baz
    . quux
```

when each of the `bar`, `baz`, and `quux` subexpressions are long. The following is bad form:

```
foo x = bar $ baz $ quux $ x
```

There are two reasons this is less preferable. First, fewer subexpressions can be copied and pasted into an auxiliary definition during refactoring; with all `($)` operators, only subexpressions that include the `x` argument are valid refactorings, whereas with `(.)` and `($)` operators even subexpressions like `bar . baz` or `baz . quux` can be pulled out into a separate definition.

The second reason to prefer `(.)` is in anticipation of a possible change to the fixity of `($)`; currently, `($)` is `infixr`, meaning it associates to the right, like so:

```
foo x = bar $ (baz $ (quux $ x))
```

However, `($)` would be useful in more expressions if it were `infixl`; for example, something like

```
foo h = f (g x) (h y)
foo h = f $ g x $ h y
foo h = (f $ g x) $ h y
```

...which currently cannot be expressed without parentheses. The "bad form" example, when parsed with an `infixl` application, would be

```
foo x = ((bar $ baz) $ quux) $ x
```

which means something significantly different. So, future-proof your code by avoiding this form.

Comment: I've also occasionally seen things like `bar . baz $ quux x` or `bar (baz . quux $ x)` or other mixtures, typically when other infix operators are involved, or when specific function applications are being conceptually emphasized.

Comment: IMO, the fixity argument is less compelling than the fact that the compositional style lets you refactor the pipeline into a function with a simple cut-and-paste.

Comment: With its current fixity, if you have `bar $ baz $ quux $ x`, this is equivalent to `bar . baz . quux $ x`. The latter is, of course, encouraged over the former.

Comment: I really can't see the precedence or fixity of `$` changing - the point of `$` is to have low precedence and you can't get lower than 0, so `f $ g $ h x` is fine. Personally I dislike `f . g . h $ x` as it uses two operators (so two concepts - composition and application) when the `$` form just uses one.

Comment: @stephentetley Is it more clear to say the associativity of `($)` might change? As you say, the precedence level is right where it ought to be.

Comment: The associativity may change and associativity is part of fixity declarations, so I think what you already have is fine. Of course, "associativity" would be fine too.

Comment: I had never heard of it but apparently there really is some [discussion](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/ChangeDollarAssociativity) on changing the associativity of ($)