# How to "show" a constructor in lower case

Tags: haskell, show

Suppose I'd want to create a new data type and make the constructors showable, only in lower case instead of their upper case definition. For example:

```
data Day = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday| Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday
```

By adding *deriving Show*, ghci would print them as "Monday, Tuesday.. etc." To get it to show "monday, tuesday.. etc" I've tried to make a special instance of show:

```
import Data.Char

strToLower :: [Char] -> [Char]
strToLower (x:xs) = toLower x : strToLower xs
strToLower [] = []

instance Show Day where
   show d = strToLower (show d)
```

where the first occurrence of show should designate my new amended show function (which will be called everytime I print) whereas for the second I intend the normally derived version of show, to get from the constructor name to a String.

Of course this doesn't work (circular definition) as the ghci has no clue to my separate meanings of the word "show" but I can't figure out how to let him know the distinction, for both versions need to be named show, the first because that's what print calls to and the second because it's a predefined haskell function which can give me a String out of a constructor name. I've tried

```
show d = strToLower ((showsPrec 0 d) "")
```

but this comes down to the same circular definition, at least that's what I guess from the ghci getting stuck in a loop.

I understand why constructor names need to begin with an upper case letter, but showing them lower case shouldn't be a problem, should it? I know I could just define my show function for every case separately, e.g. `show Monday = "monday"` `show Tuesday = "tuesday"` etc, but I'm only using the days of the week as an example here and my real data type consists of 64 constructors so I think it would be more elegant to solve it differently somehow.

Is it possible to dig into the haskell definition of show and alter a copy of that code? This is the only possible solution I can think of but I don't know how to do it, if it is possible at all. Probably not. So other solutions are very welcome as well!

Thank you for taking your time,

Jelle (Haskell beginner)

Comment: Why can't you write `showDay day = map toLower . show` and use `showDay` instead of `show`?

Comment: In addition to the other answers, it might be worthwhile to answer your direct question (how can I use the derived `show` to implement my own `show`?), for which the answer is "you can't". It is a fundamental rule of Haskell that each class may have _at most one_ instance for a given type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can actually do this using the `Typeable` and `Data` classes.

To do this you need the `DeriveDataTypeable` extension, turn it on with `-XDeriveDataTypeable` or by  putting the following line at the start of the file that defines your type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
```

You can now import the needed modules:

```
import Data.Data
import Data.Typeable
```

And derive `Typeable` and `Data`:

```
data Day = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday| Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday
     deriving (Typeable, Data)
```

Now you can use `toConstr` to get a constructor representation:

```
instance Show Day where
   show = strToLower . showConstr . toConstr
```

But see the other answers on whether you'd really want to, instead of simply using a `showDay` function or your own type class instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I prefer this solution because it's easy and it preserves the pure notion of "showable" instead of having to resort to a "fake" (my)show function. Thanks again!

Comment: Still, I wouldn't build such a `Show` instance because its output is not valid Haskell code. But this is a really nice way of defining a `showDay` or custom-typeclass showing function, +1. — On an unrelated note, writing expressions of the form `f $ g $ x` is [kind of deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8618901/745903), use the equivalent `f . g $ x` instead (so in this case `show d = strToLower . showConstr $ toConstr d`).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks, and interesting point about `f $ g $ x`. After writing the above, I thought about changing it to `show = strToLower . showConstr . toConstr`, since I like pointfree functions as long as they are still readable. Will do so now. But I did not know that there was an (albeit probably very little) chance that `$` might change associativity in the future... not sure if I like this, however, because I think the "pipe-style" of chained `$`-operators is pretty intuitive in cases where you cannot make it pointfree by only using `.`. Will keep it in mind, though.

Answer (score 6):

Instances of the `Show` class are supposed to work in such a way that you can copy-paste its output and use it as Haskell code. If you now have lowercase constructors, these won't work as such. They would work with the `newtype` approach,

```
data DayInternal = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday

newtype Day = Day DayInternal
monday = Day Monday
tuesday = Day Tuesday
wednesday = Day Wednesday
thursday = Day Thursday
friday = Day Friday
saturday = Day Saturday
sunday = Day Sunday

instance Show Day where
    show (Day d) = strToLower $ show d
```

Of course, that leaves you with redundancy you probably don't like. You could build this automatically with Template Haskell, but I doubt that's really worth it.

What I really think is that you want is not a `Show` instance at all, but rather some kind of pretty-printing. You could roll your own

```
class MyNiceShow s where
  myNiceShow :: s -> String

data Day = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday
      deriving (Show)

instance MyNiceShow Day where
  myNiceShow d = strToLower $ show d
```

Comment: I dont think writing all those functions (even by TH) will be of any use because you can't pattern match on them and I think most of writing those constructors will be used in pattern matching.

Comment: Also adding a new typeclass for just writing show is pretty useless as you will have to define instances for other classes or use the function directly which just boils down to what dave suggested (write a myshow function).

Comment: Nope, you can define `MyNiceShow` in a way to use`Show` for all other types (using #OverlappinInstances, but hey..).

Comment: Actually you need FlexibleInstances and UndecidableInstances, too, I tried it out...

Comment: If you're using `MyNiceShow` for pretty-printing to users, you'll probably find in most programs that there's actually a very limited set of types you want to do that with (especially since users who want their output not to be in Haskell syntax wouldn't like many of the built-in `Show` instances). So it isn't *that* much work to create a bunch of instances for `MyNiceShow`, and you get the added benefit that when you later discover you want to change the output format of some other type that already has a `Show` instance it's easy.

Answer (score 3):

Well don't know if you can do that for the same datatype, but a workaround I can see is to wrap it into a newtype as

```
newtype D = D Day
instance Show D where
    show (D d) = strToLower $ show d
```

Now you can use type `D` instead of `Day`.

Comment: ...at the cost of having to write `(D Monday)` instead of `Monday`. (Not saying this is a bad idea, necessarily, just that it has its downsides.)

Comment: @dave4420 Well he can ofcourse define some other function instead of `show`, but `show` instance might be used by other library functions so he can not just modify that. Its the tradeoff I am talking about, thats why I said it is a workaround, with some cost to pay for writing those extra constructors.